# How to access gmail with different IP in loop

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I want to login into gmail with an account and perform some actions and sign out of it and login with different account(from my account list) but this time with different originating IP.

```
 with open('mygmailAccounts.json', 'r') as f:    
    accountsList = json.loads(f.read())

 driver = webdriver.Firefox();
 for eachaccount in accountlist:
    gmail_Login();
```

Is it possible that when script try to login with different account, call should go with different IP? Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30940490/631619

Answer (score 1):

Use a proxy server, like this with chromedriver and Python

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=46.102.106.37:13228')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='ChromeDriverPath', chrome_options=options)

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=46.102.106.37:13228')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='ChromeDriverPath', chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Both set looks identical. is this how I should use it?? Also, please confirm if this proxy snippet will switch the driver to new IP on each call?

Comment: I believe these options work for a browser session.